# Unexpected Rounding Behavior

Tags: postgresql

I have some PostgreSQL code that produces results that are unexpected (or entirely expected, and I am trying to understand why.)

My theory is that it has something to do with `date_part` returning a `double precision` and having this be divided by an integer before rounding, but I am really not sure.
Ex:

```
ROUND(45/10) = 4
ROUND(45.0/10) = 5
```

I have verified this behavior on:
`PostgreSQL 11.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5), 64-bit`
and:
`PostgreSQL 10.7 (Ubuntu 10.7-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit`

```
SELECT
       ROUND(DATE_PART('minute', '2019-07-30 23:55') / 10) AS "ROUND(5.5)",
       ROUND(DATE_PART('minute', '2019-07-30 23:45') / 10) AS "ROUND(4.5)",
       ROUND(DATE_PART('minute', '2019-07-30 23:35') / 10) AS "ROUND(3.5)",
       ROUND(DATE_PART('minute', '2019-07-30 23:25') / 10) AS "ROUND(2.5)",
       ROUND(DATE_PART('minute', '2019-07-30 23:15') / 10) AS "ROUND(1.5)",
       ROUND(DATE_PART('minute', '2019-07-30 23:05') / 10) AS "ROUND(0.5)"
```

My expectation is that the results would be:

```
6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

The actual results are:

```
6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 0
```

Comment: [Integer division](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a92153a9a159df273c797d6d19a612e4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using imprecise data type:

```
SELECT
 ROUND(DATE_PART('minute',TIMESTAMP '2019-07-30 23:55')::NUMERIC(10,5) / 10) AS "ROUND(5.5)",
 ROUND(DATE_PART('minute',TIMESTAMP '2019-07-30 23:45')::NUMERIC(10,5) / 10) AS "ROUND(4.5)",
 ROUND(DATE_PART('minute',TIMESTAMP '2019-07-30 23:35')::NUMERIC(10,5) / 10) AS "ROUND(3.5)",
 ROUND(DATE_PART('minute',TIMESTAMP '2019-07-30 23:25')::NUMERIC(10,5) / 10) AS "ROUND(2.5)",
 ROUND(DATE_PART('minute',TIMESTAMP '2019-07-30 23:15')::NUMERIC(10,5) / 10) AS "ROUND(1.5)",
 ROUND(DATE_PART('minute',TIMESTAMP '2019-07-30 23:05')::NUMERIC(10,5) / 10) AS "ROUND(0.5)"
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d3c600f0b2131bd1566c1905ca903f1d)**

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful. From this answer I additionally found https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT which reinforced what you said. I will ensure to use `numeric` for calculations.